# Read two characters consecutively using scanf() in C

Tags: c, input, character, scanf, input-buffer

I am trying to input two characters from the user `t` number of times. Here is my code :

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    char a,b;

    for(i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        printf("enter a: ");
        scanf("%c",&a);

        printf("enter b:");
        scanf("%c",&b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Strangely the output the very first time is:

```
enter a: 
enter b:
```

That is, the code doesn't wait for the value of `a`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `scanf("%d", &t)` leaves a newline in the input buffer, which is only consumed by `scanf("%c", &a)` (and hence `a` is assigned a newline character). You have to consume the newline with `getchar();`.

Another approach is to add a space in the `scanf()` format specifier to ignore leading whitespace characters (this includes newline). Example:

```
for(i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    printf("enter a: ");
    scanf(" %c",&a);

    printf("enter b: ");
    scanf(" %c",&b);
}
```

If you prefer using `getchar()` to consume newlines, you'd have to do something like this:

```
for(i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    getchar();
    printf("enter a: ");
    scanf("%c",&a);

    getchar();
    printf("enter b:");
    scanf("%c",&b);
 }
```

I personally consider the former approach superior, because it ignores any arbitrary number of whitespaces, whereas `getchar()` just consumes one.

Comment: ...or you can place a space before `%c` in `scanf`---> `scanf(" %c", &a)`.

Comment: @haccks Yep, true, I'll add this to my answer - thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: just adding getchar before the loop does not work..however adding getchar just at the beginning of the loop and at the end of loop works  in this case.

Comment: @babji Yep, using `getchar()`before the loop only won't work. I realized that, but then edited my answer and forgot to remove this part. Thanks for noting though, I have removed it now.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: Thanks, knew something new after reading your wonderful answer.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code it's perfect it should read T times A and B but it replaces A and B every time the for each loop.

Use array or hash table to store effectively

Comment: The question is just about the input, not processing a and b, so you're answering a different question, not this one.

Comment: Sorry didn't get ur question hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Some formats used with `scanf` makes a newline trimmed from `stdin` but others don't. Reading using `"%d"` falls into latter category. You need to read a newline `'\n'` before reading into

```
scanf("%c", &a);
```