# C program to accept two characters

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to make a C program which accepts two character consecutively and then print them, but I'm getting some anomaly in the output.

The program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c1, c2;
    printf("\n Enter two characters : ");
    scanf("%c%c", &c1, &c2);
    printf("\n The the characters are %c and %c ", c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output

> Enter two characters : a
>   The the characters are a and

In the output without asking for the second character it is directly going to the next `printf()` statement. Why is this happening?

Comment: Always show your input in questions concerning I/O.

Comment: this can help you -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099976/taking-two-characters-consecutively-in-c

Comment: The result is perfectly valid: `scanf` is reading 2 characters: `{a}{\n}`, and so the output will be _"[..]characters are {a} and {\n}"_. Perfectly valid and predictable

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem @nos And what difference is being created just by adding a space between the two `%c`?

Comment: @rajaTHEKING: the leading space in `scanf` skips over all whitespace characters that might be in the buffer (including newlines). Alternatively you can use something like this: `%[^\n]`. All format specifiers automatically skip whitespace, except for `%c`, `%[]` and `%n`. There's a lot of ways to tackle these kind of situations either way, most of them will end with saying that you should avoid `scanf` whenever you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
scanf(" %c %c", &c1, &c2);
/*     ^  ^               */
```

When you hit return key after first character, `'\n'` is read in `b`. Using space before `%c` instructs to ignore any white-space(space, tab, newline etc).

Further read: [What does space in scanf mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582322/what-does-space-in-scanf-mean)

Comment: .. perhaps check the return value from `scanf`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c1, c2;
    printf("\n Enter two characters : ");
    scanf(" %c %c", &c1, &c2);
    printf("\n The the characters are %c and %c ", c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

The space between the `%c` consumes the trailing left out newline `\n` character.

Comment: In the comment they say that while giving the inputs I'm entering a and '\n'.. So what difference your code is creating ?

Answer (score 0):

add a space in between `%c` in `scanf()` function. When you press enter eg. `\n` after first input `c1`, it gets stored in `c2` in your case. By using space in between `%c` instructs to ignore any white-space(space, tab, newline etc).

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        char c1, c2;
        printf("\n Enter two characters : ");
        scanf("%c %c",&c1,&c2);
        printf("\n The the characters are %c and %c ", c1, c2);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The space you added in the format string is what changed things.

Comment: yup I got it, my mistake.