# How to prompt the user to loop in C?

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf, do-while

I’m new to C and currently doing a Jack ‘N Poy that requires the project to restart when the user prompt it like by answering y. However, I can’t seem to grasp its pattern. Have tried it on C++ and it worked but not on C. Can anyone help? I want the user to have the ability to play again after finishing the game.

Here is the code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>

  int main (){
  char firstPlayer, secondPlayer, again;
  do{
  printf("Jack 'n Poy)\nEnter Player 1 input: ");
  scanf("%c ", &firstPlayer);
  
  printf("Enter Player 2 input: ");
  scanf("%c", &secondPlayer);
  
  switch (firstPlayer){
      case 'x':
      switch (secondPlayer){
          case 'x':
          printf("Draw");
          break; 
          case 's':
          printf("Player 2 wins");
          break;
          case 'p':
          printf("Player 1 wins");
          
      }
      break;
       case 's':
       switch (secondPlayer){
          case 'x':
          printf("Player 1 wins");
          break;
          case 's':
          printf("Draw");
          break;
          case 'p':
          printf("Player 2 wins");
      }
      break;
       case 'p':
       switch (secondPlayer){
          case 'x':
          printf("Player 2 wins");
          break;
          case 's':
          printf("Player 1 wins");
          break;
          case 'p':
          printf("Draw");
       }
      break;
      default:
      printf("Invalid input");
      
}
      printf("\nPlay again? (y/n)");
      scanf("%c", &again);
}
while (again == 'y');
printf("Thank you for playing");

return 0;
}
```

Have also tried adding a substitute variable for the y and yes it does loop, but the loop skips the first question.
[image]

Your help are very much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a technical description of a problem. [ask]

Comment: Remove the spaces after ```%c```, add the spaces before ```%c```. And it's a very poor SO etiquette to edit the question after it has received answers/comments. It invalidates them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read two characters consecutively using scanf() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099976/read-two-characters-consecutively-using-scanf-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the format to:

```
 scanf(" %c", ...);
```

in all `scanf`s. Note the `' '` before `%c`

Answer (score 0):

Your `again` is a string. You can use `strcmp(expectedString,inputString)` as the condition at `while`. You will need to `include` the `string.h` header file to be able to do this.

Alternatively, change `again` to `char` type, i.e. `char again;`

And then use `%c` in the last scanf, i.e. `scanf("%c", &again);`. You may face skipped character scenario if spaces or newlines are entered. In that case, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100065/5249021) for guidance.